# Getting child div from parent div in a large document

Tags: javascript, class, html

I would like to use javascript to manipulate the style of child divs when their parents are clicked. Because the parents follow the same style and are large in number, I have them as classes rather then IDs. How might I access a class div's class child and will that affect all the children or just those that belong to the clicked parent?

i don't have code yet, I'm just thinking in the planning stage. How might you go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'll link you through to what I ended up doing for my issue similar to this:  [My previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22292003/3296133)

Basically, you want to get the parent div class (e.g. `var ParDivClass = document.getElementsByClassName (".divParentClass")`). This inserts the elements (the children) of this class into an array, in this case called ParDivClass. Then, to create an array of all the children of the given parent class, you have to filter by that (e.g `var ChildOfParClass = ParDivClass.item(0).childNodes`).

This then puts all the children of the selected parent, into an array called ChildOfParClass.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Good for you figuring it out with straight js, but I actually just found a nice solution with jquery! Will update question with solution.

Comment: Awaiting the update with the jquery, will be interesting to see and I look forward to learning that little bit more! Nice find.

Comment: I actually added it as an answer, but I can mark it as a solution for another few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured something out with jquery, so close enough!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //hide child initially
    jQuery(".child").hide();
    //toggle the child on click of parent
    jQuery(".parent").click(function()
    {
        jQuery(this).next(".child").slideToggle(200);
   });
});
```

You can adjust the speed of the collapse by changing the number inside slideToggle.